# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on array in custom prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, undefined

I got a definition that looks like so:

```
function className(data)
{
    this.dataRecords = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, item)
    {
        this.dataRecords.push(new dataRecord(item.record));
    }
}
```

But for some reason js does not think this.dataRecords is actually an array.
I modified the code to do the following:

```
function className(data)
{
    var array = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, item)
    {
        array.push(new dataRecord(item.record));
    }
    this.dataRecords = array;
}
```

This works fine, but i'd rather push the data to the actual object, in stead of now having to do another `this.dataRecords = array;` to get the job done. I want to give the class functions for manipulating this.dataRecords from my class's perspective( like addRecord and removeRecord), which with this technique, becomes a little tedious.

Is there any way I can make js recognize the array(this.dataRecords) as an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because inside the callback of `each`, `this` refers to the item from the array.

**FIX1:**

Store the value of this before entering `each`:

```
function className(data) {
    this.dataRecords = [];
    var that = this; // that is this
    $.each(data, function(key, item) {
        that.dataRecords.push(new dataRecord(item.record));
//      ^^^^ use that instead of this
    });
}
```

**FIX2:**

Use [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), because they don't get bound to any `this` (they don't have a `this` so the only `this` is your class):

```
function className(data) {
    this.dataRecords = [];
    $.each(data, (key, item) => {
        this.dataRecords.push(new dataRecord(item.record));
    });
}
```

**FIX3:**

bind the callback of `each` to your class using [**`Function.prototype.bind`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function className(data) {
    this.dataRecords = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, item) {
        this.dataRecords.push(new dataRecord(item.record));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

when `bind` is called on a function, the return value will be another function that has its `this` value always set to the parameter of `bind`. So, in the above we define a function that accepts two arguments `(key, item)`, and then we bind it to `this` (`this` in this case is the instance of the class as we are still in the scope of the constructor), and we pass the returned value of `bind` (which is a new function similar to the original one except it has its `this` set to the instance of the class) to `each`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is a great way to have 'this' always refer to the class's instance.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm editing my answer to add some links to the docs. Could be useful.

Comment: I did attempt your 2nd fix, since I like that one most, but my IDE(phpstorm) does not agree on the syntax. Might there still be some syntax error in your example?

Comment: @RobBiermann That arrow function is ECMAScript version 6. You probably have an old version of the IDE. Most of the recent browser undersand **arrow functions**.

Comment: Hey you thief ;-) (you stole my accepted status) Arrow functions is a relatively new thing and is not present in many older browsers. So I recommend against them presently unless a transpiler is used. The solution that uses bind I also recommend against just because the cases where it might hurt more than help since bind itself is a method that returns a new copy of the function. Consider the case when using a bound function as a listener callback. It has to be stored somewhere for you to be able to remove it later. Possibly adding a memory leak.

Comment: Still. I give you a thumbs up because of the thorough answer.

Comment: I have to agree with Hampus on the fact that many browsers might not support the 2nd and 3rd fix. However I do believe that this is the most helpful answer, not only for me, but for future cases, and people who use MDN actively as well. PS: I will still go for the first fix for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to different things in the two different contexts. A slight (and very commonly used) modification will make it work.

```
function className(data) {
    this.dataRecords = [];
    var that = this;
    $.each(data, function(key, item) {
        that.dataRecords.push(new dataRecord(item.record));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and adequate response, this was the spot on solution I was looking for! :)